# Drupal 7 Search Result in a custom form

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-forms

I am building a simple custom module to search a certain node type and displaying it in the same page as the form. It is like the search function. The problem is how to display the result below the form with paging-teaser node style?

The code is:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_help().
 *
 * Displays help and module information.
 *
 * @param path 
 *   Which path of the site we're using to display help
 * @param arg 
 *   Array that holds the current path as returned from arg() function
 */
function book_search_help($path, $arg) {
  switch ($path) {
    case "admin/help#book_search":
      return '<p>' . t("Displays book search page") . '</p>';
      break;
  }
}

function book_search_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['book/search'] = array(
    'title' => 'Pencarian book',
    'description' => 'Halaman pencarian book',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('book_search_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

  return $items;
}

function book_search_form($form, &$form_state) {
$form['cari'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    //'#title' => t('Pencarian'),
    //'#attributes' => array('class' => array('container-inline')), 
    '#tree' => TRUE,
  );

 $form['cari']['pilihan'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Pilihan Pencarian'),
    '#options' => array(
      '1' => t('Option 1'),
      '2' => t('Option 2'),
      '3' => t('Option 3'),
      '4' => t('Option 4'),
      '5' => t('Option 5'),
      '6' => t('Option 6'),
      '7' => t('Option 7'),
      '8' => t('Option 8'),
    ),
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('container-inline')), 
    '#default_value' => $category['umum'],
//    '#description' => t('Set this to <em>Yes</em> if you would like this category to be selected by default.'),
  );

 $form['cari']['kata'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Kata Kunci'),
  '#size' => 50,
  '#maxlength' => 256,
 );

  $form['cari']['submit'] = array('#type' => 'submit', '#value' => t('Cari'),'#submit' => array('book_search_submit'),);

  if (isset ($form_state['hasil'])){
    print render(node_view_multiple($form_state['hasil'], 'teaser')) . theme('pager');
  }

  return $form;
}

function book_search_submit($form, &$form_state) {


  //db_query("INSERT INTO {table} (name, log, hidden) VALUES ('%s', %d, '%s')", $form_state['values']['name'], $form_state['values']['access']['log'],  $form_state['values']['hidden']);
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery;
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', 'mytype')
    ->pager(20)
    ->propertyCondition('status', 1); // in case you need it
    // ->fieldCondition('field_customfield3', 'value', $user->uid)
    // ->fieldCondition('field_customfield4', 'value', $anemailaddress);
  $results = $query->execute();

  if (isset($results['node'])) {
  $news_items_nids = array_keys($results['node']);
  $news_items = entity_load('node', $news_items_nids);
  }

 drupal_set_message(t('Your form has been submitted.'));

  $nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($results['node'])); 
  $form_state['hasil'] = $nodes;
//  print render(node_view_multiple($nodes, 'teaser')) . theme('pager');
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
```

I modified the code so it can dynamically building queries according to selection options. The trick to display the result is by appending the result html in the back of the form code using `$form['#suffix'] = $html;`. It resulting inconsistency in the result paging. **Is there any way to improve it or make it right?**

Modified Code:

```
function book_search_help($path, $arg) {
  switch ($path) {
    case "admin/help#book_search":
      return '<p>' . t("Displays book search page") . '</p>';
      break;
  }
}

function book_search_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['book/search'] = array(
    'title' => 'Pencarian book',
    'description' => 'Halaman pencarian book',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('book_search_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

  return $items;
}

function book_search_form($form, &$form_state) {
$form['cari'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#tree' => TRUE,
  );

 $form['cari']['pilihan'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Pilihan Pencarian'),
    '#options' => array(
      '1' => t('1'),
      '2' => t('2'),
      '3' => t('3'),
      '4' => t('4'),
      '5' => t('5'),
      '6' => t('6'),
      '7' => t('7'),
      '8' => t('8'),
    ),
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('container-inline')), 
    '#default_value' => $category['umum'],
  );

 $form['cari']['kata'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Kata Kunci'),
  '#size' => 50,
  '#maxlength' => 256,
 );

  $form['cari']['submit'] = array('#type' => 'submit', '#value' => t('Cari'),'#submit' => array('book_search_submit'),);

  if (isset($_SESSION['hasil'])){
    $html = drupal_render(node_view_multiple($_SESSION['hasil'], 'teaser')) . theme('pager');
    $form['#suffix'] = $html;
  }

  return $form;
}

function book_search_submit($form, &$form_state) {


  $query = new EntityFieldQuery;
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node');
  switch($form_state['values']['cari']['pilihan']){
    case '1':
    $query->entityCondition('bundle', array('montype','book'), 'IN')
    ->fieldCondition('body', 'value', $form_state['values']['cari']['kata'], 'CONTAINS');
    break;

    case '2':
    $query->entityCondition('bundle', 'montype')
    ->fieldCondition('body', 'value', $form_state['values']['cari']['kata'], 'CONTAINS');
    break;

    case '3':
    $query->entityCondition('bundle', 'montype')
    ->fieldCondition('field_dosis', 'value', $form_state['values']['cari']['kata'], 'CONTAINS');
    break;

    case '4':
    $query->entityCondition('bundle', 'montype')
    ->fieldCondition('field_efek_samping', 'value', $form_state['values']['cari']['kata'], 'CONTAINS');
    break;

    case '5':
    $query->entityCondition('bundle', 'montype')
    ->fieldCondition('field_peringatan', 'value', $form_state['values']['cari']['kata'], 'CONTAINS');
    break;

    case '6':
    $query->entityCondition('bundle', 'montype')
    ->fieldCondition('field_interaksi', 'value', $form_state['values']['cari']['kata'], 'CONTAINS');
    break;

    case '7':
    $query->entityCondition('bundle', 'montype')
    ->fieldCondition('field_kontraindikasi', 'value', $form_state['values']['cari']['kata'], 'CONTAINS');
    break;

    case '8':
    $query->entityCondition('bundle', 'montype')
    ->propertyCondition('title', $form_state['values']['cari']['kata'], 'CONTAINS');
    break;

    default:
    break;
  }
    $query->pager(20)
    ->propertyCondition('status', 1); // in case you need it


  $results = $query->execute();


$_SESSION['hasil']  = node_load_multiple(array_keys($results['node']));
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
 drupal_set_message(t('Your form has been submitted.'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had a quick rewrite of a couple of aspects, didn't test it so there might be the odd typo or two.
The only thing I've really added other than a couple of standards is the use of $form_state['storage'], which is primary used for multi-step forms, but I've used it a couple of times to achieve what you are trying to do. (https://www.drupal.org/node/1850410)

Also, the use of render instead of drupal_render, just does some additional checking before sending it over to the drupal_render function.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function book_search_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['book/search'] = array(
    'title' => 'Pencarian book',
    'description' => 'Halaman pencarian book',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('book_search_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

  return $items;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_form().
 */
function book_search_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $results = _book_search_results();
  $query = $results['query'];
  $nids = $results['nids'];

  $form['#method'] = 'get';
  $form['#token'] = FALSE;
  $form['#multistep'] = TRUE;
  $form['#redirect'] = FALSE;
  $form['#after_build'] = array('_book_search_form_after_build');

  $form['cari'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#tree' => TRUE,
  );

  $form['cari']['pilihan'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Pilihan Pencarian'),
    '#options' => array(
      '1' => t('1'),
      '2' => t('2'),
      '3' => t('3'),
      '4' => t('4'),
      '5' => t('5'),
      '6' => t('6'),
      '7' => t('7'),
      '8' => t('8'),
    ),
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('container-inline')),
    '#default_value' => $query['pilihan'],
  );

  $form['cari']['kata'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Kata Kunci'),
    '#size' => 50,
    '#maxlength' => 256,
    '#default_value' => $query['kata'],
  );

  $form['cari']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Cari'),
    '#submit' => array('book_search_form_submit'),
  );

  if ($nids) {
    $nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
    // $build = _book_search_results_node($nodes);
    $build = _book_search_results_table($nodes);

    if ($build) {
      $form['results'] = array(
        '#type' => 'markup',
        '#markup' => render($build) . theme('pager'),
      );
    }
  }

  return $form;
}

/**
 * Remove items from the form in a after_build event.
 *
 * @param array $form
 *   The drupal form.
 *
 * @return array
 *   The drupal form, post modifications.
 */
function _book_search_form_after_build($form) {
  unset($form['form_token']);
  unset($form['form_build_id']);
  unset($form['form_id']);
  return $form;
}

/**
 * Get results by using filters in the query string.
 *
 * @return array
 *   An array of node id's.
 */
function _book_search_results() {
  $values = drupal_get_query_parameters();
  $field_values = array(
    'pilihan' => FALSE,
    'kata' => '',
  );

  // @todo: You may need to update these variables.
  $cari = array_key_exists('cari', $values) && is_array($values['cari']) ? $values['cari'] : array();

  // If the user has not submitted the form.
  if (!$cari) {
    $field_values = array(
      'pilihan' => '7',
      'kata' => 'searchterm',
    );
  }
  $query = array(
    'pilihan' => array_key_exists('pilihan', $cari) ? $cari['pilihan'] : $field_values['pilihan'],
    'kata' => array_key_exists('kata', $cari) ? $cari['kata'] : $field_values['kata'],
  );


  $bundles = array('montype');
  $field_conditions = array(
    '1' => 'body',
    '2' => 'body',
    '3' => 'field_dosis',
    '4' => 'field_efek_samping',
    '5' => 'field_peringatan',
    '6' => 'field_interaksi',
    '7' => 'field_kontraindikasi',
  );
  $propery_conditions = array('title');
  if ($query['pilihan'] == '1') {
    $bundles[] = 'book';
  }

  $efquery = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $efquery->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', $bundles);;

  if ($query['pilihan']) {
    if (array_key_exists($query['kata'], $field_conditions)) {
      $efquery->fieldCondition($field_conditions[$query['pilihan']], 'value', $query['kata'], 'CONTAINS');
    }
    elseif (array_key_exists($query['pilihan'], $propery_conditions)) {
      $efquery->propertyCondition($propery_conditions[$query['pilihan']], $query['kata'], 'CONTAINS');
    }
  }

  $results = $efquery->pager(20)
    ->execute();

  return array(
    'query' => $query,
    'nids' => $results ? array_keys($results['node']) : array(),
  );
}

/**
 * Node teaser display for the results of the book search.
 *
 * @param array $nodes
 *   An array of nodes.
 *
 * @return array
 *   A renderable build array.
 */
function _book_search_results_node(array $nodes) {
  return node_view_multiple($nodes, 'teaser');
}

/**
 * Table display for the results of the book search.
 *
 * @param array $nodes
 *   An array of nodes.
 *
 * @return array
 *   A renderable build array.
 */
function _book_search_results_table(array $nodes) {
  $build = array(
    '#theme' => 'table',
    '#header' => array(
      t('Node Id'),
      t('Title'),
      t('Created'),
      t('Random field'),
    ),
    '#attributes' => array(
      'class' => array('book-search-results-table'),
    ),
    '#rows' => array(),
    '#sticky' => FALSE,
    '#empty' => t('There are no results matching that criteria.'),
  );

  foreach ($nodes as $n) {
    $field_random_field = field_get_items('node', $n, 'field_random_field');
    $random_field = $field_random_field ? $field_random_field[0]['value'] : '';

    $build['#rows'][] = array(
      $n->nid,
      $n->title,
      $n->created,
      $random_field,
    );
  }

  return $build;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @anthony it really simplify the coding. But the main problem is about paging the result. When i try to access page 2 or more, the paging is gone. I think the paging information is missing or reset-ed when the page is clicked. Also if I want the result is formated into table is it as simple as changing theme('pager') to theme('table')?

Comment: Sorry about that, I should have used the 'get' method for the form so that the pager keeps hold of the information, I'll update the code node. As for the table, at the moment, the results are shown using the core display more, I'll give you an example of a table in the code.

Comment: This is great, the pagination works but there is an error in `fetchAll()` call. It says `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll()`. Also with table result it seems there is no pagination. Could you give me links to learning resources about this? Still not grasping the concept of pagination, forms and displaying content in Drupal. Thanks @Anthony.

Comment: Another question if I may. How to persist the search keyword and selected option after form submit or access page navigation?

Comment: I've updated the code to pass not just the results but also the query back to the form, you will still need to verify the @todo marking works correctly. Hope that helps.

Comment: Btw, If I want to load a default result (default query) when the form is load for the first time, how do I do this? Thanks. @Anthony

Comment: If you see the lines under the todo in the _book_search_results function. The the part after the colon is the value when the field has no data. This could also be the case if the user specifies no values for a particular field so would probably look at adding a custom field within the form as a hidden value, that way we could be sure if this value is in the query the user has already submitted the form at some point, I'll update the code to reflect this...

Comment: I've just read your comments before the one I responsed to, I've updated the code to remove the fetchAll() method, silly mistake, this is part of db_select not EFQ. I've changed the pagination to see if this would work, aslong as the EFQ has a pager set this should function. Generally resources I would suggest drupal.org and practice. I found a good way to learn was to look through other peoples modules and refactor them. Persisting the search values would be down to sessions, just be careful if people are logging in/out as these generally get cleared.

Comment: Nice, I add a default value in the search_results function and the query works as it should. I thought before that the `$results = _book_search_results();` is not beeing called. But actualy it is always called when the form is constructed/build. It returns empty because `array_key_exists('cari', $values)` the array with index `'cari'` is not set yet when the form is loaded for the first time. It is set when the form is submitted. Am I right? Thank you Sir.

Comment: That's right, however I've just refactored the code again, the $query variable was being overridden with the EntityFieldQuery. The query will always run, it will return all the results with no filters enabled if the form is empty and then the query will be filtered further when the user makes a search. The return from _book_search_results() is a keyed array of the query (form filters) and the nids (nids of the nodes returned from the EFQ).